# Comparing string with static string

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

Here's an example of what I've tried.

```
static TARGET: &'static str = "a string";

fn main () {
  printfln!("%?", TARGET.eq(~"other string"));
}
```

I looked at `equiv` too, but no luck. The string I compare to the TARGET has to be an owned pointer string.

Comment: All fmt! related macros changed BTW. Your code will break with the next update. Take a look at here: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/fmt/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works here:

```
static TARGET: &'static str = "a string";

fn main () {

  println!("{}", TARGET == "a string");
  println!("{}", TARGET == ~"a string");

  let other = ~"a string";
  println!("{}", TARGET == other);

}
```

It prints:

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make it clear that the string had to be a pointer. Edited the question.

Comment: @ErikKronberg if `TARGET == ~"foo"` didn't work when you tried it, you should say the error message you got. (If it doesn't work, you can try forcing it to be a `&str` via `foo.as_slice()` where `foo` has type `~str`.)

Comment: You are quite right, when I was able to check up on it, I got no error messages. I must have mixed it up with something else!

Comment: I've been trying this out and found. `"a string" == other` works fine, but `other == "a string"` gives a type error!

Comment: @Adrian Ratnapala That seems like an implementation issue at the moment.